# jQuery scrollable positioning bug + jsfiddle demo

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I was trying to use the sortable function of jQuery. But there is a bug. When the containing parent position is set as **relative**, and I scroll down. It wont work. It will start working again after colliding with another element. Until then it will be placed far away. It will work fine the next time i try to sort any other element.

[Here an demostration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AESE3.gif)

Repro: https://jsfiddle.net/agef2ypo/

The code is pretty simple

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: '.sortme',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: "pointer"
});
```

I tried triggering manual update event. It didnt work. What can I do now? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [JSFiddle works](https://jsfiddle.net/98wkn25f/) if you remove the `position: relative;` to sortable elements.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: '.sortme',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: "pointer"
});

/* 
// === Wrong in JSFiddle
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: '.sortme',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: "pointer"
}).css('position', 'relative');
*/
```

---

**UPDATE**

A bit tricky but works. Essentially I simulate a first drag/drop move of 1px.

This require an external library for `simulate` function under MIT license:

- [GitHub link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate?utm_source=cdnjs&utm_medium=cdnjs_link&utm_campaign=cdnjs_library)
- [CDN link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-simulate)

[This is the result on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpv8m9tn/1/)

The JS code:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: '.sortme',
  containment: "parent",
  handle: '.move',
  tolerance: "pointer",
  helper: 'clone',
  create: function(event, ui) {

    let el = $(this).find('.sortme:first .move');
    el.simulate("drag", {
        dx: 1,
        dy: 1
    });

  }

});
```

Comment: True, but I cant remove at it is required for another component up to the tree: https://jsfiddle.net/rbLoztjw/1/ check the red part. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, great! Thanks